# bootstrap download button opening image in new window instead of downloading

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, download

i have created a bootstrap download button codeigniter, when the user clicks the download button, it should download the image on the left, so i did the following code for the button:

```html
<a id="download" type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" href="<?php echo ADMIN_IMG.'evite_images/'. $val['image'];?>" download="proposed_file_name">
    Download
  </a>
```

but instead of downloading the image on the left, its taking me to the image in a new tab. can anyone please tell me why is it behaving like this, thanks in advance

Comment: The button does not and will not determine how the server handles a request for a particular filetype. This is because the headers that "inform" the browser that the file should be presented as a download and not as content for the browser itself come from the back-end.

Comment: sorry,i didnt understand what you said. can you please show as an answer, i just want to download the image which is present next to the download button

Comment: @zubairnazer check this link maybe can help you https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Comment: please inform yourself how a link is handled [via controllers](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html) in a MVC framework like Codeigniter and also about the [CI Download Helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html?highlight=download#download-helper) in addition to @JavierLarroulet comment